# Razor VB - Pass a Null value if a Request variable is empty

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005, razor

I've been trying so hard to find a solution for this, but no luck. I'm fairly new to VB and SQL, but this shouldn't be too hard. I've inherited a lot of code and there's not too much room to change db attribute types or anything.

I'm trying to run an UPDATE query using parameters in Razor, like so:

```
    Dim updateCommand = "UPDATE [tblJobRating] SET [ProjectManagement] = @0, [ProjComments] = @1, [Schedule] = @2, [SchedComments] = @3 WHERE [JobRatingID] = @4"
```

All of the columns in question need INT values, but I have one exception where I need to pass it a null value (passing another number or zero won't do). Essentially a "N/A" value for the user.

I assign the variables from Post requests, like so:

```
Dim projMgmt = Request.Form('projMgmt')
' ...
Dim sched = Request.Form('sched')
```

I have the "N/A" value posting no value right now (or it can be a string and I can check for IsNumber if need be, I guess). But when I call the query execution, it enters the value as a 0.

```
db.Execute(updateCommand, projMgmt, projComments, sched, schedComments, ratingId)
```

It needs to be a NULL value for the backend to work properly. I've tried type checking and passing `Nothing`, `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null`, etc., but it either gives conversion errors or sets to 0. How can I pass it properly?

**Edit:** I left out the first param in the db.Execute method, passing in the updateCommand. Edited for clarity.

Comment: Can you supply additional information about your db.Execute method -- doesn't look familiar to me.  What params does it accept?

Comment: The db.execute command uses placeholders to pass values to the sql statement (@0 = projMgmt, @1 = projComments...) and is used in Razor to prevent sql injection. I forgot to pass in the first param, the updateCommand that it executes. I edited that now. http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/form-basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your vb variable definition. I assume you have an integer, it needs to be a nullable(of integer) all the way through to the SQL. This can also be written as integer?.

Comment: I think I follow. It seems that initial variable declaration of integers default to a 0 value, but declaring it as nullable would let me check for the number being passed in and keep it null if I need to. But how is this different than declaring Dim projMgmt = Nothing, which didn't work? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx

Comment: You are using implicit declarations which means that the variable you declare is of the same type as the variable you assign to it. VB will also do widening type conversions automatically (C# won't). When you Dim projMgmt = Nothing, you get a variable of type object. With the one in your code you get a string type (probably). Your database is dealing with these as best it can. Dim projMgmt As integer? = Nothing will give you what you need. Remember the string "" is not the same as Nothing.